# Surface normals in Blender?

Tags: camera, normals

I currently have a .ply mesh, and I am trying to compute the surface normals of the blob-like object. I wish to encode the normals in an RGB map, so I tried linking the geometry node's normal to the emission shader as shown below:

[image: Node setup.]

However, I checked the output for the rendered image (in MATLAB) and the normals were certainly not right. In the preview pane, the cube looked like this:

[image: Cube preview.]

Clearly, something isn't right, as I would want the face facing the viewer to be green and not black.

Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Check what space the normals are being computer, you may need local, global (world), or camera space normals.

Comment: @nodim I wonder, is it possible to share the method you used for obtaining surface Normals? Or maybe can you take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101404/how-to-render-surface-normal-maps-in-blender) and post an answer if you know how do render surface Normal maps in Blender?

Comment: The face in the +ve Y direction is green.  The face facing you is negative green, which is black as far as the renderer is concerned.  You could use a vector math node set to Absolute if you want both directions to show as green.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get a texture with those values then just bake the Normals but select World instead of Tangent in the menu.